# How to insert my tag field into the db with array?

Tags: php, foreach, mysqli

Here is my loop but I don’t know what I should do:

```
$etiketler = 'tag,tag2,tag3,tag4';    
$var = $etiketler;
        foreach ($var as $e) {
        $keywords_data = array(
            'tag_name' => $e,
        );
        insert('cms_etiketler',$keywords_data);
    }
```

My insert function is:

```
function insert($table,$data) {
    global $db;
    $sql = $db->insert($table, $data);
    return $sql;
}
```

I’m using MySQLi db class from here: https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

How can I add these tags into my tags table one by one?

---

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution:

```
$var = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $etiketler);
```

Comment: @sharanya thanks for grammer edit. ;)

Comment: If you found your answer, either post the answer and accept it, or delete the question. We don't add "solved" to the title here.

Comment: allright i just did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution:**

```
$var = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $etiketler);
```

More info : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php